# How to add a custom text field in Magento v1.5 Catalog/Mange products/General tab in admin panel?

Tags: php, magento, attributes, product, catalog

How to add a custom text field in Magento v1.5 Catalog/Mange products/General tab in admin panel?
please help me if any body have expertise on this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Magento maintains Catalog Product as EAV structure, so it will be best (in the interest of Magento functionality & feasibility) to provide the text field as an attribute in the `General Tab` of Catalog Product details page in the Admin section.

We will go through step by step process of adding an attribute to all the Products:-

- Go to the "`Manage Attributes`" page (`Main Menu` > `Catalog` > `Attributes` > `Manage Attributes`), to find the list of all the available Catalog Attributes.
- Click the "`Add New Attribute`" button to add a new attribute.
- Provide the following in the form (**Word of Caution: Don't try to change any of the properties in this Attribute details page, unless you are sure of what you are doing.**):-

  - First we will fill up the required fields for the tab "`Properties`".
  - Provide your Attribute Code, in the "`Attribute Code`" field.
  - Let the "`Catalog Input Type`" be "`Text Field`", as you wanted to have text field only.
  - If you want to pre-populate this text field with any value, then you will need to provide that text in the "`Default Value`" field.
  - If you want to provide this attribute to all the product types, then you need not change the value of the "`Apply To`" dropdown (which by default is "`All Product Types`"). Otherwise you can change this value to "`Selected Product Types`" & automatically a list of all the available Magento Product Types will appear in another dropdown, from where you need to select your required product types for this attribute.
  - For the "`Visible on Product View Page on Front-end`" field, you need to select the value "`Yes`", if you want this text field to appear in the front-end Product details page.
  - Now we will fill the tab "`Manage Label/Options`", in the left hand panel. Click on that tab to open that tab's details page.
  - Provide the label in both the fields available which will be shown both in the front-end & in the admin section.
- Click the "`Save Attribute`" button to add this attribute.
- Magento will provide a notice that you need to re-index one / two Indexes from the "`Index Management`" section, with the link of this section provided.
- Click on that link to go to the "`Index Management`" section & re-index those indexes which are marked in red.
- Now go to the "`Manage Attribute Sets`" page (`Main Menu` > `Catalog` > `Attribute` > `Manage Attribute Sets`).
- Click on the "`Default`" row of the Set Name, to view its details page.
- Open the FTP or your local Explorer, to go inside the "`var`" folder.
- Delete the "`cache`" folder, so that configuring the attribute set do not get disturbed due to the Cache.
- Coming back to the browser, go to the rightmost section (named "`Unassigned Attributes`") to find your created attribute in the list.
- Drag that attribute into the middle section (named "`Groups`"). There will be many groups available by default. Since you want your attribute to be in the "`General`" tab, so you should drag & put your attribute in the "`General`" group only after / before any suitable attribute. Be careful in this area, as no other attribute(s) should get misplaced.
- Now click the "`Save Attribute Set`" button & your work is complete.

To check whether the above process worked correctly or not, go to the Product details page in the Admin section & in the "`General`" tab, you should be ale to find your own created attribute sitting perfectly with a text field happily among others.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But wait, in what way is this programming related?

Comment: @Peter - The PO thought about it to proceed in programming logic. :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce it .. maybe I cannot understand what you mean when you say 'Provide the label in both the fields available which will be shown both in the front-end & in the admin section.' ..

Comment: Thank you this is what i am looking for :)