# how to add a new field in catalog product ->manage categories->general information tab in magento 1.5?

Tags: magento

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a custom text field in Magento v1.5 Catalog/Mange products/General tab in admin panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193699/how-to-add-a-custom-text-field-in-magento-v1-5-catalog-mange-products-general-ta)

please help me if any one know how to add a new field in catalog product ->manage categories->general information tab in magento 1.5 ?.....thanks

Comment: You cannot understand ehat to do exactly by reading the accepted answer. You better have a look here instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193699/how-to-add-a-custom-text-field-in-magento-v1-5-catalog-mange-products-general-ta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log into admin.

Go to catalog -> attributes

-> manage attributes

Comment: the above answer is for catelog-manage products...i want to add a new field in catalog-manage categories....

Comment: thanks Tommy Cox Green...you are right

Comment: Your welcome Salim, good luck with the rest of your project.  I am learning myself and trying to support the community.  Would you mind accepting my answer if you found it was right?

Comment: @Tommy Cox Green It's not clear at all how to do it. Would any of you explain it in a clear way? Thanks